# How to customize the navigation button?

Tags: sass, ngx-admin

How to customize the navigation button?

[image: Navigation Button]

Answer (score 0):

One could customize the navigation button by editing the sass file in [/src/app/@theme/components/header/header.component.scss](https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin/blob/master/src/app/%40theme/components/header/header.component.scss#L36). The example below shrinks the button to 80% of its default given size(2.5rem):

```
.navigation {
  ...
  font-size: 2rem;
  ...
```